# simpler way to calculate a determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Simpler way to calculate this?

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & \lambda -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}$$

my method:

\begin{align*} \det A 
&= \det \begin{bmatrix}\lambda -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda -1 & 2 \\ -\lambda  & 2 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \det \begin{bmatrix} \lambda -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda -1 & 2 \\ -2 & 4 & \lambda  \end{bmatrix} \\
&= \det \begin{bmatrix} \lambda -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 4 & \lambda  \end{bmatrix}\end{align*}

After stuck for a long time, I decided to calculate by diagonal rule,

$$(\lambda -1)^2\lambda -8(\lambda -1)=(\lambda -1)(\lambda ^2-\lambda -8)$$

however I've made some mistakes.

---

The rule of **Sarrus** hinted by @Dietrich below:
$$\begin{align}
(\lambda -2)(\lambda -1)\lambda -4\lambda -4(\lambda -2)
&= (\lambda -2)(\lambda -1)\lambda -4(2\lambda -2) \\ 
&= (\lambda -1)((\lambda -2)\lambda -8) \\
&= (\lambda-1)\left(\lambda ^2-2\lambda -8\right) \\
&= (\lambda -1)(\lambda -4)(\lambda +2)\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your method is? I don't see what you're doing.

Comment: @DBF seems I've made an error. wait...

Comment: @DBF, the determinant is invariant under the first kind of row/column operation. I don't see what operation we did in the last line, though.

Comment: There. Finally fixed the formatting so it's possible to see what's going on. Now whether the computations are correct...

Comment: You may also use the Laplace's formula (since your matrix has two zero terms). More details can be found here : [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of Sarrus (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) is quite convenient here. You should obtain 
$$
\det (A)=(\lambda-2)(\lambda-1)\lambda-4\lambda-4(\lambda-2)=(\lambda -1)(\lambda+2)(\lambda-4).
$$

Comment: I've added one direct calculation, can make it more simpler?

Comment: +1 I always urge students  using this way for a $3\times 3$ matrix.